# Mkdocs unable to find modules

Tags: module, mkdocs, cp-sat

I'm trying to generate automated documentation, using :
`mkdocs = "^1.4.2"`
`mkdocstrings = "0.19.0"`
`mkdocs-material = "8.5.8"`
`mkdocstrings-python = "0.7.1"`

my mkdocs.yml looks like this :

```
site_name: Optimization Services Documentation
site_url: "https://example.com"

theme:
  name: "material"
nav:
  - 'index.md'
  - 'reference.md'
plugins:
  - search
  - mkdocstrings:
      handlers:
        python:
          setup_commands:
            - import sys
            - sys.path.append('../')
          selection:
            new_path_syntax: true
```

index.md is still the default file generated by mkdocs new.

reference.md looks like this :

```
# Reference
::: modelling.constraints
```

and modelling.constraints.py:

```
def init_constraints(groupes_chantiers: list[GroupeChantiers],
                     digraph_precedence: nx.DiGraph,
                     graph_coactivite: nx.Graph,
                     model: cp_model.CpModel,
                     **kwargs) -> None:
    """
    Adds constraints to cp_model
    Args:
        groupes_chantiers: 
        digraph_precedence: 
        graph_coactivite: 
        model: 

    Returns: None

    """
    pass
```

When I'm trying to build documentation, mkdocs serve returns:

```
INFO     -  Building documentation...
INFO     -  Cleaning site directory
INFO     -  DeprecationWarning: 'selection' and 'rendering' are deprecated and merged into a single 'options' YAML key
              File "C:\Users\9821390Z.COMMUN\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\optimisation-KWHapjG2-py3.9\lib\site-packages\mkdocstrings\extension.py", line 121, in run
                html, handler, data = self._process_block(identifier, block, heading_level)
              File "C:\Users\9821390Z.COMMUN\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\optimisation-KWHapjG2-py3.9\lib\site-packages\mkdocstrings\extension.py", line 185, in _process_block
                warn(
INFO     -  DeprecationWarning: Parameter `only_exported` is deprecated, use `implicit` instead.
              File "C:\Users\9821390Z.COMMUN\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\optimisation-KWHapjG2-py3.9\lib\site-packages\mkdocstrings_handlers\python\handler.py", line 195, in collect
                unresolved, iterations = loader.resolve_aliases(only_exported=True, only_known_modules=True)
              File "C:\Users\9821390Z.COMMUN\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\optimisation-KWHapjG2-py3.9\lib\site-packages\griffe\loader.py", line 181, in resolve_aliases
                warn(
INFO     -  DeprecationWarning: Parameter `only_known_modules` is deprecated, use `external` instead.
              File "C:\Users\9821390Z.COMMUN\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\optimisation-KWHapjG2-py3.9\lib\site-packages\mkdocstrings_handlers\python\handler.py", line 195, in collect
                unresolved, iterations = loader.resolve_aliases(only_exported=True, only_known_modules=True)
              File "C:\Users\9821390Z.COMMUN\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\optimisation-KWHapjG2-py3.9\lib\site-packages\griffe\loader.py", line 189, in resolve_aliases
                warn(
ERROR    -  mkdocstrings: modelling.constraints could not be found
ERROR    -  Error reading page 'reference.md':
ERROR    -  Could not collect 'modelling.constraints'
```

It works if I replace reference.md by `::: modelling` but returns only private functions `__cached__, __file__, __package__`...
This is just making me sure that modelling is a python package, but I can't get what's inside it.

Furthermore, I'm comparing it with another project for which `mkdocs serve` works well, so I'm quite confused.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter a similar problem with a python project. `mkdocs serve` only works for the python files in a few of the project folders but does not work for the python files in some of the other folders (`ERROR - Could not collect ...`).

I copy a python file from a folder that does not work to a folder that works and then this file can be successfully collected by running `mkdocs serve`.

In my case, it is discovered that the folders that work all have a `__init__.py` file that identifies them as regular package folders.

My problem is resolved by adding a `__init__.py` file to a folder from which we want `mkdocs serve` to collect files and making it a regular package folder.

Hope this helps in your case!